# Including a form from a separate file with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form to create a new `Player` in `/players/new.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for(@player) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

which I want to include in the home page.

If I just copy-paste the whole form I get this error: `undefined method`model_name' for NilClass:Class`

I can include the form in an iframe

```
<div>
  <iframe src=../players/new.html>
</div>
```

but this shows the whole page with headers and footers.

How can I include the form, ideally directly from the file (i.e. no copy-paste)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `form_for` requires at least `@player` to be present

if you really want to include that form on your home page then in your home controller action initialize new Player instance:

```
@player = Player.new
```

but you must be aware that views of `PlayerController` (or whatever controller you have that form created for) can rely on having access to helper methods from `PlayerHelper` so you might need to also include that in your `HomeHelper`

Comment: ... except that if the home page is index and is visited frequently, you are instantiating a Player each time.  Also actually processing the form may get tricky as you may now need to modify the index method to handle Player creation. So I would make the action of the form be a different method, which creates the player and redirects back to index.

Answer (score 1):

I would move the fields into a partial and reuse those on the homepage and the other pages. Keep in mind that will have set the url in the `form_or` for it to work.